# Telerik Radgrid Batch editing, on copy of edited text of textbox from keyboard (CTRL + C) the grid reloads

Tags: c#, telerik, radgrid

I have implement Batch editing in radgrid with  4 columns , on batch edit of a cell, I want to copy the edited text by hitting the CTRL + C but  the grid reloads after CTRL + C and the focus moves to the grid from the edited cell.Other Keyboard shortcuts ctrl + V and ctrl + X works as expected.

OnKeyPress Client event is not fired when ctrl key is pressed.

Any Inputs on this would be helpfull.

In the below demo link if I edit the Quantity Per Unit column and try to copy by CTRL +A then CTRL + C , the grid just reloads without copying.I want to copy the edited cell data.

http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/grid/examples/data-editing/batch-editing/defaultcs.aspx

Comment: Post your RadGrid markup code.

Comment: Did you figure this out?  I'm curious. If not, you can try Telerik support.

Comment: Yes @ariscris , I have raised this issue to the telerik support team, thanks for answering.

Answer (score 0):

You can catch the CTRL+C via the OnKeyDown event in the RadGrid.

```
RadGrid1.Attributes.Add("onkeydown", "onKeyDown(this,event);");
```

Then in onKeyDown, you can check for CTRL+C:

```
function onKeyDown(sender, event) {
    if (event.keyCode == 67 && event.ctrlKey) { // CTRL+C
        alert("Copying!");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem. It seems as if it is related to the properties AllowKeyboardNavigation and EnableKeyboardShortcuts. If both of them are set to True then CTRL+C does not work but instead rebinds the grid. Setting one of them to false will make CTRL+C work.

Unfortunately setting EnableKeyboardShortcuts to false will also make the grid unable to accept the characters å, ä and ö (and will disable keyboard shortcuts, if that is important to you).

Setting AllowKeyboardNavigation to false will disable the ability to use tab to navigate between cells.

I'm using the 2014 Q3 release of the components.

[image: feature/bug matrix]

I have filed a support ticket to Telerik regarding this.

**Edit**:
I got a reply from Telerik. It seems as if CTRL+C is the shortcut for Cancel (when EnableKeyboardShortcuts is set to true). Adding CancelChangesKey="Q" to KeyboardNavigationSettings makes the problem go away.

For me, as I want to be able to enter å, ä and ö, it looks something like this:

```
<ClientSettings AllowKeyboardNavigation="true">
    <KeyboardNavigationSettings CancelChangesKey="Q" EnableKeyboardShortcuts="true" />
</ClientSettings>
```